# Why I can't have duplications for quadratic residues when I have some $p$ prime greater than 2 ?(and also the max numb. of quad.res)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've started studying number theory and I am not understanding the following result:

> Let $p$ be a prime other than $2$. If there are two numbers $u$ and
>    $v$ such that $u^2\equiv v^2 \mod p$ then $u^2-v^2 \equiv 0 \mod
>  p$, $u^2-v^2=(u-v)(u+v) $ is a multiple of $p$,so $u \equiv -v \mod
>  p $ or $u\equiv v \mod p $. Thus when we write down the quadratic residues
>    $0^2,1^2,\cdots,(p-1)^2$, there can be no duplications,*except that* 
>   the last  $(p-1)/2 $ are copies of the first $(p-1)/2 $ nonzero
>   squares.

(i)
I find the author's wording a little bit ambiguous to me ,namely what  does it mean that there can't be duplications,except that (...) ?

I've tried to make this clear to me by writing for example the quadratic residues of $5$,or $0,1,4,4,1,0,\cdots$ ,from this I see that there are duplications ,so I am misunderstanding what the author is really saying...

(ii) For the last part I am trying to prove that for a prime $p$ ($p>2$) I can have a maximum of $\cfrac{(p+1)}{2} $ residues.

For this part this is what I've done :

We have that $$p  \equiv 0 \mod p \implies p^2 \equiv 0 \mod p$$

Then , $$ p^2 +4 \equiv 4 \mod p ,\space \space p^2+4 \equiv 2p+4 \mod p \implies (p-2)^2 \equiv 4 \mod p $$ I am clueless now of what to do next.

Comment: In the title I've tried to include also the second question I've asked.I don't know how to make it fit  in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) The author means simply there are no ‘triplications’ of quadratic residues. This is due to the fact that in a field, a quadratic equation has at most $2$ roots.

(ii) There are exactly $\dfrac{p+1}2$ quadratic residues. Indeed the non-zero elements can be written as $\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots,\pm\frac{p-1}2$, and they're alll distinct since $p\neq 2$. The squares of each of these groups are distinct (same reason as in (i)), hence there are $\dfrac{p-1}2$ non-zero squares. Counting $0$, there are
$$\frac{p-1}2+1=\frac{p+1}2\enspace\text{quadratic residues}.$$

Comment: Then the first part can be applied to any integer and not just for primes greater than $2$,why to make a specification ?For the second part how do you know that you can write the last non zero element as $\cfrac{p-1}{2}$ ?

Comment: For (i), your hypothesis, if I understand well, is that $p$ is an odd prime (‘other than $2$’). ,For (ii), this is because $-k\equiv p-k$ for all $k=1,2,\dots,p-1$.

Comment: I've thought about it till now.If we ignore $0$ we have $\cfrac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues given that ,take $5$ for example,we have that $1^2 \equiv 4^2, 2 \equiv 3^2 $, and after this we just get the same pattern but in reversed order,is this correct ?(I know this is trivial for you,but as you see it took me an entire night....)

Comment: * $2^2 \equiv 3^2 $

Comment: That's correct, but you'll sleep better next night if you note, before computing the squares, that $4\equiv -1,\ 3\equiv -2 \pmod 5$.